# Threshold exceeded using Add-pnpfile

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

We are trying to use the PowerShell SharePoint module, Pnp.PowerShell, more exactly the `Add-Pnpfile` cmdlet, but, our site has to many files on the list (more than 5000), so we are getting a error: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold

Does its possible to modify this threshold?

Thank you for your time.
Best regards

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's a cmdlet issue, instead it seems like SharePoint is warning you not to exceed 5000 docs.  From some researching it looks like people put items into multiple libraries? See this for more- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoints-threshold-exceeded/m-p/1634809

Comment: Sharepoint can store more than 5000 files, but only can list 5000. When i use the cmd, SPO is listining, so this trigger the issue. I want to know if is possible make a bypass to this opperation.For example using something like "TOP N" rows